# Does anyone know the name of this template?

Tags: templates

Although I like LaTeX, I am a bit bored of the default template and would like to use something looking more like this:
http://www.ens-lyon.fr/DSM/SDMsite/M2/stages_M2/Debierre2012.pdf
Does anyone the name of this specific template? Or something looking alike?

Comment: Suggest you just email the author and ask.  Usually works for me.

Comment: Don't you just *hate* the "This page accidentally printed on" thing?

Comment: The template has nothing special, apart from the title page. The page geometry has been changed and also the header, but it's a standard `article`. The mix of New Century Schoolbook with Computer Modern for math is surely a no-go.

Comment: Do you really like this? The whole thing is not well designed (see egregs comment, see the textwidth). If you don't like the default templates have a look on tufte-latex, classicthesis or so. The documentation of the memoir gives some nice suggestions about good design. The internet is full of templates (and lots of them look better than the linked one).

Comment: LaTeX uses classes, not templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific template that looks like that, but if you do the titlepage yourself, having

```
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

should give you something close.